# Variable Selection Method for Unordered Categorical Variable with Different Levels - in R

Tags: r, multivariate-analysis, missing-data

[image: DataTable]

I have a table with 6 different fields. Each field is entered manually by a different person at a different location. Each field has different number of levels - Tab1: 2, Tab2: 2, Tab3: 4, Tab4: 2, Tab5: 3, Tab6:5.

I want few fields to be filled automatically based on other fields, effectively reducing number of people needed for the job. I guess, for that I need to know which fields correlate with each other...(For example in the table - Tab1, Tab2, Tab4 looks completely correlated and A in Tab1 correlated completely with brick in Tab5, and B in Tab1 correlates with ae in Tab6).

What would be the best way to tackle this problem? I was trying to calculate Chi-square correlation but was unsuccessful.

Note – My real dataset has 100+ fields with some fields having 1000+ levels. Data also has many NAs in different fields.